# Django 'dict' object has no attribute 'user_id'

Tags: django, django-views

I get the following error **'dict' object has no attribute 'user_id'** but not sure I understand the error. Since user_id is available from the queryset.

Error happens at the last line of code

```
users_who_played = UserEvent.objects\
            .values('user_id')\
            .annotate(total_season_points=Sum('points'))\
            .filter(event__season_id=season.id)\
            .order_by('-total_season_points')\

    for i, user_who_played in enumerate(users_who_played):

        try:
            user = UserSeason.objects.
                   get(user=user_who_played.user_id, season=season.id)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[The `.values()` method on querysets returns a queryset that returns dictionaries instead of model objects when you iterate over it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) -- so `user_who_played` is a dict, which means you should access the user id by writing `user_who_played['user_id']` instead of using dot attribute syntax.

If you want to retrieve only certain fields from the database but still want to deal with model objects, an alternative is to use [the `.only()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) instead of `.values()`.