# django 'dict' object has no attribute 'sexo'

Tags: python, django

I've got the following code:

```
def nuevo_animal_accion(request):
    if request.GET["caravana"]:
        animalnew = Animal
        form = request.GET.copy()
        caravana=form.get('caravana')
        idlotefk = Lote.objects.get(idlote=form.get('lote'))
        raza = form.get('raza')
        padre = form.get('padre')
        madre = form.get('madre')
       # fechanacimiento = form.get('nacimiento')
        sexo = form.get('sexo')


        animalnew.objects.create(caravana=caravana, idlotefk=idlotefk, raza=raza, padre=padre,madre=madre, sexo=sexo)
        # Ver como capturar errores por si no se pudo crear
        return HttpResponse("Se ingreso el nuevo animal")

def listar_animales(request):
    animales = models.Animal.objects.values().all()
    for animal in animales:
        listaa[animal.caravana] = animal.sexo

    return render(request,"animal/listar_animal.html", listaa)
```

Thing is that it gives me the atribute error.
I've searched and there is a relative post ([Django 'dict' object has no attribute 'user_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632197/django-dict-object-has-no-attribute-user-id)) but I can't figure out how can I use it on my code so please help.

Comment: use **`animales = models.Animal.objects.all()`**

Comment: Thanks. It works partially. Now my problem is that it seems that the función that adds animals doesn't work because listar_animales returns an empty list

Comment: Correction: the add function works because the objects apear in the database and if I add a print, it works, but nothing apears in the html...

Answer (score 0):

animales = models.Animal.objects.all() solves the problem, thanks Arakkal